# Can the absolute value of fixed sized minors be arbitrarily ordered?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants

In an $m \times n$ matrix $X$, there are exactly $\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{r}$ minors of size $r \times r$. Is it always possible to construct a real matrix $X$ such that the absolute value of the determinant of the $r \times r$ submatrices is arbitrarily ordered in modulus?

In other words, for $I \subset \{1,\dots,m\}$, $J \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$, let $X_{I,J}$ be the submatrix of $X$ with entries in positions $I \times J$. Given an ordering on the set $$\{I_i \times J_j \mid I_i \subset \{1,\dots,m\}, J_j \subset \{1, \dots, n\}, |I_i| = |J_j| = r\}$$
does there exist a matrix $X$ such that the set $\{|\text{det}(X_{I_i,J_j})|\}$ has the same ordering in modulus?
Has this question been answered somewhere in literature that someone could point me towards?

Comment: A somewhat related question was studied by Farber and Postnikov in https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01434. They are in particular interested in what orderings of minors can occur in a *totally nonnegative* matrix.